# How to set html string on title attribute of any html element in angular 4?

Tags: html, angular, formatting, tooltip, angular4-forms

I want to have formatted htmlString on any HTML element's title as a ***tooltip***:

Data contains html string

```
   <span [title]="data | safeHtml"> Help? </span>
```

But in this way it's not rendering formatted text instead same HTML string is displaying when hovering on help.

Any other way around on the same?

Comment: Without code, we can't help you. It highly depends on how you handle tooltips. If it's by CSS, with a library, with a custom component ... With just a line, we can't possibly help you.

Comment: What does your safeHtml pipe look like? Also, I asume you're aware angular 4 (your tagged version) needs DomSanitizer and it's services?

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for something like $scope.trustAsHtml() in angular 4?